# Open android app programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to open another app when clicking a button in my app. How can I achieve that?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.test");
```

Comment: check the answer at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Comment: Did you do any previous research before comming here and asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't start "applications" in Android, but "activities". If the activity is not in your process, you need the full class name - just as you did in your demo code.

You need to know the exact activity name in order to open it.